# Unable to use word prediction with Onboard keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I cannot use word prediction in the OnBoard on-screen keyboard. Word prediction is turned on in settings and shows the word choices if no other program is used. When I open Libre Writer  then OnBoard does not show the word choices any more. Using Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you for your help in advance.